# Detect time change on ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I know that apple does not have access to the time api so we cannot manipulate it, but I am experiencing a problem that I have a timekeeping application, that the user can change the time and mark the time with the wrong time, on android i can control and block this

Would I be able to offline check the real time and compare it with the phone time to find out if there were any manual time changes by the user?

Comment: you would need to check a timeserver or some other external reference

Comment: Up-voted @Jason comment and thought you'd like to know why. I live in the US (Eastern Time Zone or for now GMT-4) and later this morning I plan (like I've been for several months now) to get tomorrow's daily puzzle in the one game app I use, by setting my date/time to Sydney Australia. You *need* to do two things. First, you **cannot** block the user setting a different time zone. Period. But you **can** store (usually in UserPreferences) how far the offset **was** to GMT and see if it's changed. Note - I'm *very* old school, have called it GMT since I was in grade school. UT == GMT.

Comment: As you mean you want to be able to check the real time when offline. I think you can write some code in your application to calculate the real time as the user can not change the interval of seconds on IPhone. And you only believe the time which gets from the timeserver which you believe in.